# In Rails 3, using Formtastic and Devise, generic routes producing errors when adding a new entry for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise, formtastic

I have a very simple rails 3 program with 2 models: a user model for Devise and a writing model that captures a text field and the user's id.

My routes file is pretty basic:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :writings
root :to => "users#index"
```

And my form for writings, using Formtastic, is as well:

```
<% semantic_form_for(@writing, :html => {:method => :put}) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :main %>
<%= f.input :user_id, :collection => current_user, :as => :hidden %>
<%= f.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

When I try to create a new writing, the form looks great, but then when I hit submit, I get the following error:

```
No route matches "/writings"
```

I've run rake routes, and everything else seems to be working on, and I am using the default generate scaffold from rails, so the controller is the out of the box controller.

Any ideas on where I went astray?

Comment: Can you try doing `<% semantic_form_for @writing do |f| %>`?

Comment: @Augusto, you should put this comment as an actual answer because I'm fairly sure it will solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, try putting the declaration of the form like this

```
<% semantic_form_for @writing do |f| %>
<%= f.input :main %>
<%= f.input :user_id, :collection => current_user, :as => :hidden %>
<%= f.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

I've the idea that when you specify the `:html` parameter, you "override" some defaults in formtastic. Sorry, I'm not an expert on formtastic. I've used a bit and then decided to go for [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) :).